# Change page layout in the middle of a LaTeX document

Tags: layout, latex

I'm looking for a way to change some page layout dimensions in the middle of a LaTeX document. The reason is, I'd like to have smaller margins and longer lines in the "References" section of my `report` document (basically because short lines aren't so important there and I can save space).

In my preamble I have (works fine):

```
\setlength\textwidth{130mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{14.6mm}
```

In the document I simply try to re-set them at the right point but they're ignored.

```
... last paragraph ends here.

\newpage
\setlength\textwidth{150mm}      % +20mm text width
\setlength\oddsidemargin{13.6mm} % -10mm left margin (so it stays centered)

References ...
```

The `geometry` package is useful but only for global adjustments in the preamble, so I can't use it here. Is it not possible to change the page layout *at some point* in the document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the [`changepage`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=changepage) package in CTAN does what you're looking for but I can't say that I've ever tackled this problem myself.

Comment: That does it, thanks!
I only had to add two lines to get what I wanted: `\usepackage[strict]{changepage}`
and in the document: `\changepage{}{20mm}{}{-10mm}{}{}{}{}{}`

Answer (score 8):

The geometry package offers facilities to do this.

Comment: No, it doesn't. With the `geometry` package, adjustments can be made only in the preamble.

Comment: From the abstract to the geometry documentation "The page layout can be changed in the middle of the document with \newgeometry command."

Comment: OK, I see, that would've done the job. I was using my local LaTeX documentation (1.5 years old). `geometry` couldn't do it back then.